# How to create a threaded progress bar in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm creating a Tkinter GUI application using Python and one of the function in this application is pinging different IP addresses. I'm trying to show an undeterminate progress bar during the pinging process but I can't seem to make it work. Here is what I have tried:

```
def pingSwitches(ipDictionary):
    validIPDictionary = {}
    switchCounter = 1
    popup = tk.Tk()
    popup.wm_title("Processing...")
    progress = ttk.Progressbar(popup, orient="horizontal", length=len(ipDictionary.keys()), mode="determinate")
    progress.pack()
    progress.start(50)
    popup.mainloop()

    for name, ip in ipDictionary.items():
        #progress.step(1)

        response = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-n", "1", ip],stdout = subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]

        if((b"unreachable" in response) or (b"timed out" in response) or (b"demande" in response)):
            print(ip + " is down")
        else:
            validIPDictionary[name] = ip
            print(ip + " is up")

        print("Pinged " + str(switchCounter) + " of " + str(len(ipDictionary.keys())) + " total ips")
        switchCounter = switchCounter + 1



    progress.stop()
    popup.destroy()
    return validIPDictionary
```

The problem is when I run the program, I can see that the code stops at the `popup.mainloop()` line and it does not continue. If I put the `popup.mainloop()` after the pinging process, the popup appears after the pinging is done, rendering it useless.

How can I make the popup appear while my code is pinging? Is it only by multithreading?

Comment: Is this function called by non-Tk code? Or is there a main Tk application running and you want a progress bar to appear over the top of it?

Comment: This function is called by Tk code. There is a main Tk app running and i want the progress bar to appear over it.

Comment: Only run _ONE_ mainloop at a time. Create and use classes and overloading for your "Popup" and define what starts after creation inside its `__init__` function.